# Not able to create lookup relationship of same object on Activity Object

Tags: lookup, custom-field, event, activity

I have already created activity custom field of type **Lookup(user)** on Activity object. I want to create one more custom field of type **Lookup(user)** on Activity object, but I am getting validation error saying:

There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Lookups on activites must have a unique domain. You can not have multiple relationships to the same object.".

Can anyone please help me to resolve the above issue?

Thanks and regards,
Amit

Answer (score 4):

Because of the complexity of the Activity objects, you're only allowed one lookup to a specific type of object (e.g. User) for custom activity lookup fields. There is no workaround or resolution. You won't be able to add another field that looks up to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions it might help you.. goto Object Manager-> Activity -> Fields & Relationships -> Deleted Fields -> in action -> Erase|undelete if you undelete it then it will show that label in Fields & Relationships Erase = Delete Permanently[image]